# Facebook comment/like url

Tags: facebook, url, comments, facebook-like, subdomain

Am having difficulty with the url for the facebook comment and like plugins. if I put in a simple url like "www.example.com" it works fine but my app is on a subdomain and uses querystrings to differentiate between different page states. So a sample url would be something like "facebook/example.com/index.php?id=001". However it appears facebook doesn't like this and keeps saying it is unreachable.

I can't believe facebook would limit the scope like this. Someone else must have encountered this. Any suggestions?

Comment: theres no such limitation imposed by facebook. are you testing it on your development machine? make sure that url is publicly accessible. if possible post the url here

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and this will show the tags Facebook is detecting on your page -in particular check your og:url tag isn't ommitting the URL parameters

Answer (score 0):

Facebook posts have an id something like 123456789012345_123456789012345.

The part prior to the underscore is the page id.  The part after is the post id.  The URL would be https://www.facebook.com/pageid/posts/postid, or https://www.facebook.com/123456789012345/posts/123456789012345.